# Dirichlet Process posterior with partially observed data

Tags: posterior, conjugate-prior, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

Suppose I dipose of a set of independant observed couples $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N, y_N)$ from a joint distribution $P(x,y)$. Furthermore, I suppose that the random distribution $P$ as a Dirichlet prior
$P\sim DP(\alpha, P_0)$ where $\alpha$ is a concentration parameter and $P_0$ is a centering measure. Then, we can deduce from conjugacy of the Dirichlet process that the posterior is:
$P|(x_1,y_1),...,(x_N, y_N) \sim DP(\alpha + N, \frac{\alpha}{\alpha +N}P_0 + \frac{1}{\alpha + N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{(x_i,y_i)})$

Is there a similar conjugacy property which would allow me to write a similar posterior in the case where I only observe incomplete data ?
Let me explain:
Suppose again that $P$ is a joint distribution over couples $(x,y)$ with a Dirichlet prior $P\sim DP(\alpha,P_0)$ but I only observe independant $x_1,...,x_N \sim P_x$ where $P_x$ is the x-marginal in $P$. Is it possible to write the posterior $P|x_1,...,x_N$ as some Dirichlet distribution ?

Thank you in advance for your help.